# Visual studio code not autocompleting my javascript methods

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code

I am writing automated tests for a webshop using Visual studio Code, webdriverIO and javascript/nodeJS

Everything works fine, but I can't seem to get vs code to autocomplete my methods (I am using a page object model, pageobjects which contain methods are called in tests).

This is my login pageobject with a method to login a user (just an example, actual pageobject contains many more methods) :

```
class LoginPage{

    login(username, password) {
        browser.setValue('#ShopLoginForm_Login', username)
        browser.setValue('#ShopLoginForm_Password', password)
        browser.click('button=Login')
  }
}

module.exports = { LoginPage };
```

This is how I call it in the testfile:

```
describe('login test', function() {

    const LoginPage = require('../../pages/loginPage').LoginPage;
    loginPage = new LoginPage
    const Menu = require('../../pages/menu').Menu;
    menu = new Menu

    it('should be able to login with valid credentials', function () {
        browser.url(url)
        menu.gotoLoginPage()
        loginPage.login(username, password)
    });
});
```

Every time I want to call a method in a test, it does not autocomplete the methods name, forcing me to write it out full, leading to many unneccesary typo's. Other types of methods, like webdriverIO browser.click, are autocompleted just fine.

I have tried the same code in webstorm, and there autocomplete does work.

Does anyone know what I can do to get VS code to autocomplete my methods?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

pity that no-one was able to answer. I eventually found the answer myself. I will post it here for reference

in my imports:

```
const LoginPage = require('../../pages/loginPage').LoginPage;
loginPage = new LoginPage
```

I am forgetting to declare the new instance of the class. The right way should have been;

```
const LoginPage = require('../../pages/loginPage').LoginPage;
var loginPage = new LoginPage
```

An alternative way would have been to make my methods static, which removes the need for instantiating the class altogether

Answer (score 0):

I struggled to use auto-suggest in vscode with webdriverio.

This links helped me.
https://webdriver.io/docs/autocompletion.html
https://webdriver.io/docs/pageobjects.html

You answer is right. instanciate the page.
In the official doc, they export class with 'new'

```
export default new LoginPage()
```